# Adding background color to alternate set of 'n' number of elements using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to add background color to alternating set of **'n'** number of elements. Say for example,  the first **'n'** number of  elements will be **red** and the next **'n'** number of  elements will be **black** and so on.. repeating the loop of red and black.

Please ignore the number **4** in the
**grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto)**
It is supposed to be dynamic

I can't change the HTML structure nor can I do it using `<table>`

Can this be achieved only using **css**? If not a **JS** answer would also be appreciated

```css
.table {
  margin-bottom: 20rem;
  border: grey 0.5px solid;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-cell {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 1em;
 border: grey 1px solid;
}

.table-cell:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.table-row {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use sass in your project?

Comment: If you cant use sass, an easy only css solution would be something like doing "a lot" of :nth-child(x) statements where x is a multiple of 4. So nth-child(4)/8/12/16/... so you have a few colors repeating

Comment: yes I can use sass and there will be only 2 colors repeating

Comment: I mean that just feels like a table tbh, can you put the same structure into a table and do it by `<tr>`?

Comment: The content is dynamic and I'm not supposed to do it with <tr> table structure

Answer (score 2):

Yes using `Xn+y` but in multiple selectors, this cannot be done with a single selector.

```css
.table {
  margin-bottom: 20rem;
  border: grey 0.5px solid;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-cell {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  border: grey 1px solid;
}

.table-cell:nth-child(8n+4),
.table-cell:nth-child(8n+3),
.table-cell:nth-child(8n+2),
.table-cell:nth-child(8n+1) {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.table-row {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think thats the absolut smartest way to do it, when the number 4 isnt dynamic.

Comment: The number of cells in each row is not predictable so this wouldn't work

Comment: Then this is not possible with CSS

Answer (score 1):

I would try dividing each row into a `table-row` then you can use the following styles to set your alternating `background-color` rule.

```css
div.table-row:nth-child(even) {background: #ffd110}
div.table-row:nth-child(odd) {background: #e1e1e1}
```

I added another row to demonstrate.

```css
.table {
  margin-bottom: 20rem;
  border: grey 0.5px solid;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-cell {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 1em;
 border: grey 1px solid;
}


.table-row {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  display: grid;
}

div.table-row:nth-child(even) {background: #ffd110}
div.table-row:nth-child(odd) {background: #e1e1e1}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is a nice approach but the content is dynamic and I can't change the html structure

Answer (score 0):

```
`.table {
  margin-bottom: 20rem;
  border: grey 0.5px solid;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-cell {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 1em;
 border: grey 1px solid;
}

.table-cell:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: black;
}

.table-cell {
  background-color: red;
}

.table-row {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  display: grid;
}`


<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
    <div class="table-cell">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about your solution.